# Can the word "schism" be used in this way?

Tags: word-choice

> It is the only time when I don't feel a [schism](http://goo.gl/jUVl1) in my soul.
>
> It is the only time when I don't feel a [schism](http://goo.gl/ceVwS) of the soul.

Looking at the dictionary meaning (linked), schism seems to have a political or religious context. So can it be used the way it has been in the given sentence? If not, what other words could be used in its place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this a very proper use. Although historically the word entered the English language to signify a division of spiritual or political allegiance, it has been used since the middle of the 19th century with more personal reference:

> It is a prejudice, as disastrous as it is unfounded, that there can be a schism between the heart and the intellect, to the advantage of either. -*cited in [OED 1](http://archive.org/stream/oed8barch#page/n215/mode/2up)*

*Schism* suggests something more profound and radical than, say, *division* or *ambivalence*.

I prefer *schism **in***, reflecting *division* or *cleft* or *crack* **in**.

Comment: Thank you. You mean you prefer "a schism in my soul" to "a schism of the soul"?

Comment: @Soulz Yes, exactly.

Comment: OP presumably has his own concept of what a "soul" is, but I can't really conceptualise one as being made up of warring factions. You'd surely need to have some personal awareness of independent consciousnesses / logical positions within your "soul", to feel that they were somehow in (theological?) disagreement with each other.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Zwei Seelen wohnen, ach, in meiner Brust"-Goethe. The 'divided consciousness' or 'divided self' has been a primary theme of modernism since Byron, maybe since Rousseau, right down to Laing and Sartre.

Comment: I can certainly understand how *consciousness* or *self* could be described "divided", since I assume we're talking there about something we are actually aware of. I don't often come across people who deny having something you might call *consciousness, self*. But lots of people don't even accept the *existence* of a "soul" - even supposing you believed you had one, how could "you" be aware it was experiencing internal conflict?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Because *soul* does not signify, for everyone, some theological abstraction or something metaphysical and imperceptible but the self itself, the sense of identity.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I take it you disagree with the suitability of "schism" in this context? I did a Google search and I see it being used by sociologists(?). For example: “Schism in the soul, schism in the body social, will not be resolved by any scheme to return to the good old days (archaism), or by programs guaranteed to render an ideal projected future (futurism), or even by the most realistic, hardheaded work to weld together again the deteriorating elements [of civilization]. Only birth can conquer death―the birth, not of the old thing again, but of something new.”
― Arnold Joseph Toynbee

Comment: @Soulz: Yes, I do feel it's not a very appropriate term. You'll note that your cited example is actually talking about schism in *the body social*. I don't know why it's juxtaposed with *soul*, but I suspect we're looking at a metaphorical usage there. Obviously *society* and *the body social* are made up of multiple conscious entities who can meaningfully hold mutually antagonistic positions, and thus split into warring ideological factions. But can an individual's (metaphoric?) *soul* argue over philosophical points *with itself?* For you, maybe, but not for me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But this is metaphysics, not English. You maintain a monolithic soul, but others--Plato, Lucretius, Dryden, Dr. Johnson, the Kabbalists, Goethe, Clough, Laing, countless poets and theologians--maintain the soul is or may be divided. The language accommodates all these perspectives. As for *schism*, the word denotes only a split or cleft, and need not imply rational disputation over theological principles.

Comment: @ StoneyB: Sure, at the "literary, poetic" level you can write like that. I wouldn't have a problem if this question had been asked on writers.se. I don't know what it tells us, but from Google Books, [schism in my soul](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22schism+in+my+soul%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1): 8 hits; [shiver in my soul](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22shiver+in+my+soul%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1): 141 hits...

Comment: ...by contrast, [schism in **his** soul](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22schism+in+his+soul%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1): 340 hits, [shiver in his soul](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22shiver+in+his+soul%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1): 58 hits. It looks as if writers tend to *feel* (shivers, etc.) in ***their own souls***, but are happier to "intellectualise" schisms/conflicts in ***other people's souls***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, nobody's going to buy a book about the schism in my soul, but lots of people may be interested in the schism in Paul's or Byron's or Nietzsche's.

Comment: @ StoneyB: Yup. If you want to go down in the annals of history, I guess you've got more chance if you're [a man at war with himself](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a+man+at+war+with+himself%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

Answer (score 0):

Schism is when a religious organisation or group splits in two.

Moses led the Jews who schismed from Samaritanism.

The Roman Catholic church were a schismatic offshoot of Orthodox Christianity.

Shi'ite Islam is a schism from Sunni Islam.

Schisms therefore connote a deep and irrevocable fissure, with no hope of repair.

Otherwise, that would be *an ecumenical matter*, as Father Ted would say.